# Using xcode build script to change icon.png / app name (iphone)

Tags: iphone, xcode

Anyone have any idea how to use xcode's build rules to swap out the icon file and application name depending on the appid?

I'm building multiple apps that all build from the same binary.  I'm hoping to have the icon and app name be dependent on the appid or something of this nature.

Does anyone have an good resources on xcode build scripts or care to offer some advice on this issue?  Expert needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need build scripts for that. You can create different targets, and assign specific resources to specific targets.

Here's some documentation on the subject;

- [Understanding Xcode projects](http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/xcodeprojects.html) (Apple)
- [Xcode build system guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeBuildSystem/100-Targets/bs_targets.html) (Apple)

Comment: So far this has worked pretty well; Thanks for the information.  However I wonder if this is sustainable in the scenario where there is potentially hundreds of targets.  Is this sustainable?

Comment: Hundreds of targets? I suggest you read the app approval guidelines before you do that :-)

Comment: I don't understand what you are referring to Philippe?

Comment: To clarify; I'm building a generic app that customizes itself based on information on our servers.  Each app will be an identical binary; with the exception of the icon and appId. The application communicates with the server and the server tells the app how to set up it's UI and how to function. Are you saying that this is against Apple's app approval guidelines?  I'm aware of other competitors in this space; so that would be surprising.  They have all been approved.

Comment: Submitting different apps with (almost) identical functionality is not allowed. And since you're talking about "hundreds", I doubt that Apple will like that

Comment: Phillippe can you point me in the direction of this rule in the app approval guidelines?  I cannot find this?  Have you actually seen this rule; or are you just stating an opinion?  There are already tons of applications out there that are duplicates of each other.

Comment: Remember the application changes it's look and feel based on the owner's styling / construction.  Each app will look different and contain different content.  I can't imagine apple would not allow this.  There are already tons of apps that are using this process.

Comment: 2.11: Apps that duplicate apps already in the App Store may be rejected, particularly if there are many of them. 2.13: Apps that are primarily marketing materials or advertisements will be rejected. 12.3: Apps that are simply web clippings, content aggregators, or a collection of links, may be rejected

Comment: Cool none of those will be violated by my product.  Thanks for the information; I've started using the multiple targets and it does the trick.  I figure I will need to move to a build script once I get into the high number of targets (hundreds).